# jQuery selectors for all div

Tags: jquery

I have my div like this

```
<div id="gallery-1"></div>
<div id="gallery-2"></div>
<div id="gallery-3"></div>
<div id="gallery-4"></div>
<div id="gallery-5"></div>
```

How can I select them in one jquery selector? like

```
jQuery("#gallery-*").something();
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [`attribute starts with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) at this context,

```
jQuery("[id^='gallery-']").something();
```

Or the best way would be using a common class,

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class='test'></div>
<div id="gallery-2" class='test'></div>
<div id="gallery-3" class='test'></div>
<div id="gallery-4" class='test'></div>
<div id="gallery-5" class='test'></div>
```

JS:

```
 jQuery(".test").something();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
jQuery('div[id^=gallery]').something();
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery("div")` or change `id` to `class` inside your HTML and specify the following jQuery code: `jQuery(".gallery")`.

You can also use more advanced selector syntax like `jQuery("div[id='^gallery']")`, as Rajaprabhu suggested.